# How to query mongodb filtering the results by more than one property

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Imagine you have this data model:

```
{
    "product": "Product 1",
    "category": "Category A",
    "Subcategory": "Subcat A1"
    ...
}
```

And I'd like to filter all products that are both in category Category A and in Subcat A1, how can I make this query?

Comment: This is very similar to [How to do queries on multiple attributes within an object and group the results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116350/mongodb-how-to-do-queries-on-multiple-attributes-within-an-object-and-group-th).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it:

```
db.collectionName.find({ "category": "Category A", "Subcategory": "Subcat A1"})
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also do:

db.collectionName.find({$and :[ { "category": "Category A"} ,{ "Subcategory": "Subcat A1"}] })

And in future if you want a query that has products in either 'category' or 'subcategory', try this :

db.collectionName.find({$or :[ { "category": "Category A"} ,{ "Subcategory": "Subcat A1"}] })